# rollout navigation menu - background css troubles

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

[Live site.](http://zoparealty.com/)

I have a roll-out navigation menu, where (ideally) the first set of buttons should have `20px` of `#000104` on either side. Upon hovering over "About" and "Properties," the rollout will continue with `#000104` behind the extended options.

I'm having trouble limiting the size of the first set of buttons, though. What is the best way to do this? (My main trouble is each button is a different length- About, Blog, Contact, Properties; how do I dynamically size the background color?)

[jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/498qm/)

[image: ideal image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What do you mean by "limiting the size of the first set of buttons", or "size the background color"? Please explain more

Comment: @Roy I'll attach an image to show what I mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `background: #000104` on the `a` tags, not the `ul` tags. That way, the color will not extend for the entire width of the unordered list; it will only extend as far as the `a` text. Further, to make the buttons extend out more on each side, add 20px of `padding` on the left and right side.

```
nav ul li a {
    background: #000104;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/498qm/1/)

Comment: I appreciate your help with this issue. It's so very close to being what I'm looking for, however now when I hover over "About," for example, the word "About" vanishes as the rollout options extend. How can I rectify this? Please see the updated jsfiddle for example. 

http://jsfiddle.net/498qm/2/

Comment: No problem! Just change `padding-left` in your rollout menus to `margin-left`. Their background is covering the "About" and other menu items. [See this updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/498qm/3/).